# Is it safe to delete SVN repositories after switching to Git via git svn clone?

Tags: svn, repository, git-svn

I recently changed some repositories over to Git from SVN by using git svn clone and then setting up the repository.  With a full switch to Git, is it necessary to retain the original SVN repository at all or is it safe to delete it?

Comment: Sure it's safe to delete it...you have a back up, don't you? :) Sorry...couldn't resist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say backup everything and store it forever, storage is cheap, losing work is not.

That being said, if you got all your revisions and you are happy with your git repository - you do not need your svn repo anymore.  But this all depends on the method you used to move your svn repo over to your git repo - did you get all revisions, did you change authors?  If so, move onwards and upwards - git is your SCM now.